# Does Snow Leopard have /dev/video (how to access webcam from terminal?)

Tags: macos, unix, camera

I'm curious if the built-in camera on MacBooks running Snow Leopard can be accessed from the terminal. A simple example on linux would be to

```
cat /dev/video0/ > file.blah
```

Mac's don't expose the camera as /video0/, so I'm wondering if its a differently named device or if its not exposed?

Comment: Hmm, it's not like `cat /dev/video0` works with V4L(2) anyhow, you need a few ioctls to set the stream up first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[MacFuse](http://code.google.com/p/macfuse/) used to do that. You're better off with a programmatic solution using something like [OpenCV+python](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/python/cookbook.html) for instance with a script like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import cv
capture = cv.CaptureFromCAM(0)
cv.SaveImage("file.png", cv.QueryFrame(capture))
```